# How can I rent my first home in Ireland?

Tags: rental, ireland, housing

I'm an EU citizen, so as far as I know I can relocate and apply for job in Ireland without needing a permit.

I have read a few places that in order to rent a home in Ireland, you need a reference from the previous landlord, a reference from the employer, and bank details to prove I can pay.

Since it will be my first home in a foreign country, I cannot get a reference from a previous landlord.

Regarding the employment, I would like to have a home first and establish a proof of address, before looking for a job if possible. So I cannot assume I have job by time I'm looking for apartment.

Regarding the money I have enough money to live for a year (or maybe two) based on the cost of living information I found on web (even if I'm a bit pessimistic). How can I prove I can pay? Is it enough if I can login to my online brokerage accounts or netbanks to show the money I have there? Or do I need something more official? Or is it required to have the money in the Irish bank?

Comment: No real info, but in similar situation in USA I was charged bigger (double) security deposit for the first year of my first rental.

Answer (score 1):

This is just based on my experience. I've lived in a few places around Ireland. But never in Dublin and there is a housing shortage there at the moment. The rules around renting are kind of lose so what one landlord wants and what another want will vary wildly.

> I have never been asked for a reference from a previous landlord.
>   I was asked for a reference from an employer once when I was signing a lease for a very expensive place (and probably didn't look like I could afford it). That was only once and I was dealing with a letting agency.
>   Not having a job could be a problem but it depends on how you present it. If you say you're unemployed and just need a proof of address you'll seem poor and desperate but if you're chipper and say your an IT Manager that just moved here from Germany (for example) it will come across better.

They main thing they want to know is will you be a pain for them by damaging the place, not being able to pay or being generally high maintenance. When it comes to rules in Ireland things operate a little more on the intention of the rules rather than the letter. So if you don't have the exact document they're looking for but can show them something else that's usually fine.

Small landlords vs Letting agencies.
There are pros and cons to each. Letting agencies are more officious but will generally stay out of your business. They may need more paperwork, they might clamp your car for instance. Small landlords will give your more wiggle room but may be nosy and often don't understand boundaries (I've come home to find them drinking tea in my kitchen for example) but depending on the person they may help you out with a lot and may be willing to overlook minor issues as long as your have a good relationship.

In both cases your should print out your bank statements and show them if there is any concern about having a job. citizensinformation.ie is a great resource and the people in their offices are very friendly and eager to help.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that there are no straight ways to start life in Ireland, only bent ways? 

As far as I know one need a PPS to officially rent a home (register the tenancy at the RTB), but to get a PPS you need proof of address, catch 22. If that's true I need to reconsider if I want to move at all. We are in EU, we have right, but no opportunity, so much for free movement, pfff.

Comment: @Calmarius: From http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/housing/renting_a_home/registering_a_tenancy.html "New tenancies must be registered within a month of the start of the tenancy."  So the process is: sign a lease; use the lease as proof of address to obtain a PPS; register the tenancy.  Not a problem.

Comment: @MartinBonner 

Tenancy contract is [not a valid proof of address](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/money_and_tax/personal_finance/banking/financial_institutions_and_identification.html).

Comment: I don't know about the lease but letting agents have given me letters that were sufficient as proof of address several times.

Comment: That is a link for banks.  The [rules for obtaining a PPS](https://www.welfare.ie/en/Pages/Personal-Public-Service-Number-How-to-Apply.aspx) include "Property lease or tenancy agreement" as a valid proof of address.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advice you finding a job in Dublin BEFORE relocating. It will significantly simplify the quest.

1. The housing process is the following:

1.1. You could arrange just a short stay rent from outside.

1.2. When you came to Ireland, you should hire an agent. It's practically impossible to hire anything cheap themselves.

1.3. Take a letter from your job to prove that you are a good person. Corporate landlord would accept it.

2. The registration process would unrelated to housing in the case:

2.1. Take a letter with your temporary address from your employer (practically all Irish employers know how to write it) and register for PPS.

2.2. With the letter from the employer and PPS you might go to a big Irish bank and open an account.

Please note the important that despite the housing process starts earlier, a corporate landlord would want to be payed from an Irish bank account. It means that for you would be preferable to have an account when you would speak with a landlord.

Comment: "A corporate landlord would want to be payed from an Irish bank account." Why does the sending account matter?

Comment: It increase your credibility. Irish account means that you are able to be getting payed. In Ireland and Dublin there is strong housing crisis. Every available rent gets 10-20 potential tenants. And landlord always asks you about your ability to pay the bills, then rejects all candidates that don't show it.

Comment: "Every available rent gets 10-20 potential tenants". Regardless of price? I know cheap apartments are lottery. But there should be an equilibrium somewhere.  Single bed apartments for €3000+/mo. on daft.ie, I don't believe there are 10-20 tenants lined up for those as well.

Comment: Yes, especially for 3k per month. These apparts might be renter by 3-4 persons at once. They could live in one single bedroom.

Comment: Brexit is near. Everyone moving from London.

Comment: Everything is booked at one hour commuting around Dublin. If you want get rent without problem, you should look to the distance not to the price.

Comment: In that case I have better not move then. Even a programmer job wouldn't break even as all my salary would go to the landlord... Not good.